# Mixing mutable and immutable references to a HashMap

Tags: rust

I want to create a function which gets the value associated to a key in a hashtable, and, if such value does not exist, inserts an arbitrary value (let us say 0).

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get_or_insert(table: &mut HashMap<i32, i32>, key: i32) -> i32 {
    match table.get(&key) {
        None => table.insert(key, 0).unwrap(),
        Some(v) => *v,
    }
}
```

This code does not compile:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*table` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:5:17
  |
4 |     match table.get(&key) {
  |           ----- immutable borrow occurs here
5 |         None => table.insert(key, 0).unwrap(),
  |                 ^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
6 |         Some(v) => *v,
7 |     }
  |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

Indeed, `table` is mutably borrowed in the method `insert` whereas it is immutably borrowed in the method `get`.

I can see no way to separate the mutable and immutable parts in this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great time to use the [`entry`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) method:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get_or_insert(table: &mut HashMap<i32, i32>, key: i32) -> i32 {
    *table.entry(key).or_insert(0)
}

fn main() {}
```

But you are correct, otherwise you'd have to split the call:

```
fn get_or_insert(table: &mut HashMap<i32, i32>, key: i32) -> i32 {
    match table.get(&key) {
        None => {}
        Some(v) => return *v,
    }

    table.insert(key, 0).unwrap()
}
```

However, you have to calculate the hash a second time, which is part of the reason that `entry` was created.

As a side note, `insert` returns the *previous value* for the key. If I'm reading it correctly, your `unwrap` call will always fail.

Comment: thanks, I did not know there was a `return` keyword. This is useful !